# No Internet connection on Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sdk

I downloaded the studio, xamarin added, everything seems to be okay, it’s downloading. By the end, when it’s downloaded, I create a project, for example xamarin forms, it is created, opens and everything seems to be fine, but when I go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager: an error is displayed that there is no Internet connection, but it is. It happens that he automatically suggests downloading sdk for android, I accept but a little later the same error. I have windows 7, I turned off the Windows firewall but still did not help. Please help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a check with the **[Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#requirements)** when *Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android* .

To use the Xamarin Android SDK Manager, you will need the following:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community, Professional, or Enterprise.
- OR Visual Studio 2017 (Community, Professional, or Enterprise edition). Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 or later is required.
- Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin version 4.10.0 or later (installed as part of the **Mobile development with .NET workload**).

The Xamarin Android SDK Manager also requires the Java Development Kit (which is automatically installed with Xamarin.Android). There are several JDK alternatives to choose from:

- By default, Xamarin.Android uses **JDK 8**, which is required if you are developing for API level 24 or greater (**JDK 8** also supports API levels earlier than 24).
- You can continue to use **JDK 7** if you are developing specifically for API level 23 or earlier.
- If you are using *Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 5* or later, you can try using Microsoft's Mobile [OpenJDK Distribution rather than JDK 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk).